# TinyMCE 4.6.4 update - missing plugin.min.js files

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have inherited a project that was using TinyMCE 3.5.x and I'm trying to update the project via NuGet (.net MVC project).

The TinyMCE version was updated to 4.6.4 and a bunch of plugin folders were added to my solution.

When I load my screen the TinyMCE editor opens and it looks to be in the updated editor that the demo has.  However, I am getting the following error message on screen:

> Failed to load plugin: style from url
>   http://localhost:xyz/Scripts/tinymce/plugins/style/plugin.min.js

When I look at my plugins/style folder it is there but there is no .js (or min.js) files in that folder.

[image: no js files]

I was hoping there is someone out there that can tell me where to get this file(s).  Without it, the rest of the code that the last programmer had doesn't display (i.e. custom buttons)

Does anyone know where I can find these missing .js files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TinyMCE 4 has no `style` plugin.  A plugin of that name did exist in TinyMCE 3.x but its not part of TinyMCE 4.  You need to review your TinyMCE init in general as TinyMCE 4 has many changes from TinyMCE 3 but you certainly have to remove your attempt to load the `style` plugin.

The documentation has a migration guide for moving from TinyMCE 3 to TinyMCE 4:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/migration-guide-from-3.x/

Comment: This is very helpful.  Unfortunately the dev is no longer here, do you know where the init file is where the load of the style plugin might be?

Comment: Search through your source code for something like `tinymce.init({...})` - that is how you initialize the editor.

Comment: @webdad3 Small world as well ... I see you are in Centennial.  I am in Highlands Ranch.

Comment: Small world for sure!  Hey one last question.  I think we are getting to the bottom of my issue.  I found out that the project is also referencing a NuGet package TinyMCE.MVC.JQuery that worked in tandem to the TinyMCE.JQuery package that now states it has been deprecated.  I'm guessing we have to wait for that package to be upgraded in order to use the latest version of TinyMCE.  Does that sound about right?

Comment: You don't need jQuery at all to use TinyMCE ... there used to be a helper package for people that used jQuery.  I honestly would just not use it at all but there should be a `jquery.tinymce.min.js` in the download.

Comment: I found the command that was calling the style plugin.  Once I removed it and the rest, the editor started working as expected.